# Cannot access OSM map after server reboot

Tags: 12.04, server, vmware

After rebooting my Ubuntu Server, I can't seem to access my map tile server at

```
http://192.168.86.128/osm/slippymap.html
```

(which I setup using the instructions at http://seshagiriprabhu.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/building-an-openstreetmap-tile-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/), any idea why?

I am currently running a **ubuntu-server-12.04-amd4** image on VMWare Professional.